# Ruby rbenv set up failure on WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I followed this tutorial [Setup Ruby On Rails on
Windows 10](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) and have successfully  installed Ruby 2.4 (I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and also using the `rbenv` install method). However when I enter the command `gem install bundler` I get the error message:

`/home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so: undefined symbol: parse_numeric_port`

every time, so I can't complete the exercise and install Rails. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

**Output of `gem env`**

```
    james@USER-PC:~$ gem env
/home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb:154: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/james/.rbenv/versions in PATH, mode 040777
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.0 (2016-12-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/james/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/james/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - /home/james/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin
     - /home/james/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/james/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/james/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/james/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/james/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/games
```

Answer (score 2):

WSL refers to 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' or Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. I should have mentioned that I'm running a pre-Creators Update version of Windows 10, so the root cause of the problem is the fact that my WSL is riddled with bugs, unlike the new version. Its all explained here: [windows-10-creators-update-whats-new-in-bashwsl-windows-console](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/04/11/windows-10-creators-update-whats-new-in-bashwsl-windows-console/)

Comment: I was having the same problem as you and installing Windows 10 Creators Updates solved my problem too. At the time, I found CU for download at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10. Then it was just a matter of reinstalling WSL `lxrun /uninstall /full /y` and `lxrun /install` and following the instructions are https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you I'm still having the same problem after upgrading Windows? I was sure that CU would sort everything, but there must still be problems with it.

Comment: Do you use VPN? If so, try it without being on VPN.

Comment: I don't use a VPN, sorry.